# Stub ENV doesn't work for Rspec cottroller test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, environment-variables

I come into the task for implementing https redirect for my app.
After discuss with team, we should to go with simple redirect way.

And this is the the code in controller:

application_controller.rb (version 1)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  ...

    def self.force_ssl(options = {})
      return unless ENV["FORCE_SSL"].present?
      host = options.delete(:host)
      before_filter(options) do
        if !request.ssl? && params[:controller] != "health_check"
          redirect_to request.url.gsub("http://", "https://")
        end
      end
    end

    force_ssl

  ...
end
```

The problem is when I stub the ENV['FORCE_SSL'] in controller test. It not work. ENV is correctly stub when run `pry.binding` in test suite but when I run `pry.binding` in force_ssl method when test is running, ENV['FORCE_SSL'] is `nil`.

Code in spec file:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ApplicationController, type: :controller do

  controller do
    def index
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  it "redirect to https when request in http" do
    allow(ENV).to receive(:[]).with('FORCE_SSL').and_return('true')

    get 'index', protocal: :http
    expect(response).to redirect_to %r(\Ahttps://)
  end
end
```

After that, when I change `force_ssl` to instance method gracefully.

application_controller.rb (version 2)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 ...

  before_action :force_ssl

  private

    def force_ssl
      return unless ENV["FORCE_SSL"].present?

      if !request.ssl? && params[:controller] != "health_check"
        redirect_to request.url.gsub("http://", "https://")
      end
    end
...
end
```

Just want to know the reason why this happen and are there any way to stub the ENV for test with version 1 controller code ?

Comment: `force_ssl` is already a rails method with a (slightly) different meaning: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html -- Your solution seems to be slightly reinventing the wheel, and conflicts with a built-in implementation.

Comment: Like your v1 implementation, the built-in rails `force_ssl` defines a `before_action` callback: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/force_ssl.rb#L67-L69

Comment: However, I think in answer to your question, your v1 implementation invokes the method call *before* the test runs. Therefore, it checks the `ENV` before the stub is set up.

Comment: I have used built-in `force_ssl` with `Rails.env.in?` for switching logic at the first place. But with `Rails.env.in?` we need to config nginx for the implementation. So, we decide to implement the simple https redirect instead.

Comment: Oh, you're using nginx? Then why not perform the redirect there, rather than inside the application? This is the standard way of doing it.